json-forms custom renderer tester for multiple fields
I've created a custom renderer with its tester:
import { rankWith, scopeEndsWith } from '@jsonforms/core'

export default rankWith(
  3, //increase rank as needed
  scopeEndsWith('uiSchema')
)

and it works correctly;
but I cannot figure out how to update this tester to match also other fields (not just the one whose scope ends with 'uiSchema', so let' say for example that I want this custom renderer to be used for fields with scope ending with 'uiSchema' AND 'uiDescription');

I've found inspecting the testers source code in jsonforms that it provides and and or functions to combine testers
import { rankWith, scopeEndsWith, or } from '@jsonforms/core'

export default rankWith(
  3, //increase rank as needed
  or(scopeEndsWith('name'), scopeEndsWith('description'))
)

Alternatively anyway the tester is just a function that receives 3 arguments, and you can write your own doing whatever you want inside; you just need to return a boolean telling jsonforms if the renderer has to be ranked or not:
import { rankWith, scopeEndsWith, or } from '@jsonforms/core'

export default rankWith(
  3, //increase rank as needed
  (uischema, schema, context) => {
    // avoid using the renderer if it's a layout
    if (uischema.type === 'Control') {
      // test whatever you want...
      return true
    }
    return false
  }
)

